# Checking a string for its length and letters in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, numbers, string-length

I need to write a function that will prevent the user to enter any letters, only numbers and it should be 7 digits, the user can't enter less than 7 or more, also the user can't enter number and letters (like 12345ab). How can I do that? Here's the functions that I came up with until this moment:

For the length of the string:

```
void sizeOfString(string name)
{
    while (name.length() < 7 || name.length() > 7)
   {
    cout << "Invalid number of digits\n";
    cin >> name;
   }
}
```

And this for the letters:

```
bool containLetters(string test)
{
     if (test.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") !=std::string::npos)
     return true;
     else
     return false;
}
```

But it's not really working. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: You could use the expression `(name.length() != 7)`, much simpler.

Comment: You need to `transform` the string to all lower case.  Upper case letters are different than lower case characters, especially for compares.

Comment: Yeah that makes total sense. I feel really dumb right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `isalpha()` function.

```
bool isvalid(string string1){
    bool isValid = true;
    double len = string1.length();
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(isalpha(string1[i])){
            isValid = false;
        }
    }

    if(len != 7){
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

then test

```
cout << isvalid("1234567"); //good
cout << isvalid("1s34567"); //bad
 //etc
```

Comment: How about the other function? Is there a way to combine then in single function in a "not messy" manner?

Comment: It's working! But why did you used an double for the string length? There's no half number to be stored right?

Comment: good question. If you use int, you'll get an error, because length could be many sizes (i think you should actaully use size_t). Please accept as answer!

Comment: Done! Maybe I was struggling with this int all along.

Comment: Yea, check out the docs of length for more info. But you should actually use size_t as its unsigned allowing only positive ints, etc. Cheers.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Also just so you know I'm very new to programming in general so sorry for not knowing anything.

Comment: No problem - and that is nothing to be sorry for!